# grep a pattern in some files and print the sum in each file

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep a pattern in some files and count the occurrence with the filename. Right know, if I use

```
grep -r "month" report* | wc -l
```

it will sum all instances in all files. So the output is a single value `324343`. I want something like this

```
report1: 3433
report2: 24399
....
```

The grep command will show the filename but will print every instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -c` will give you a count of matches for each file:

```
grep -rc "month" report*
```

Comment: -r means that if any of the file listed is a directory, it will enter it and its subdirectories as well (ie, if you have a "reportDIR" directory for example, your grep will continue in this dir + subdirs). But it will NOT enter directories in the current directory whose names do not match "report*". If you wanted to grep any file named 'report*' in the current dir and below, you can use @Cong Wang answer but modify it as such: `find . -name 'report*' -exec grep -Hc "month" '{}' \;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass each file to grep:    `echo report* | xargs grep -c month` .

If recursively, use `find report* -exec grep month -Hc '{}' \;`.